# How to plot this diagram?

Tags: plot, tikz-graphs

I have to plot this diagram, as shown in the picture. But couldn't find the way to do so in latex, very easy to do in paint and then include it in latex. But can I write something to get such as the following plot

[image]

Description:
 1. There are two different type of networks(or step lines), one in black and other in green. It is actually infinite across left and right (I just need to draw, just these three pairs…).
 2. The way to write inside the diagram, like the minimum distance between the wires.

Comment: you have enough reputation that you should know, that question hat 
 we can see, what you like, is not likely to receive desired attention! Please, rephrase question, show what you do so far, and upload desired image to your question.

Comment: @Zarko thanks for the valuable points. But I am not able add image through my phone (not near to my PC). Code I can only write the initials​: usepackage, begin {document} ...

Comment: well, than we (a least me) wait, that you will acces to your PC and improve your question. Meanwhile, if you have opportunity, see http://www.texample.net/ . There is may different examples. Maybe one of them close to what you like to have. Also read TikZ and PGF manual. In its first part are tutorials, which show, how to use `tikz` package.

Comment: @Zarko seems good link. Thanks, I am sure to have a look on that. I but my question was to get that plot in latex. I am just too ignorant guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below defines a command

```
\wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
```

that draws a single wire starting at `start`, where each noose is `height` high and `width` wide. The significant points (start, bends,end) get names `name-0` to `name-7`. One useful option is the color of the wire. E.g.,

```
\wire[green]{G-1}{0,0}{2}{1}
```

will draw a green wire starting at coordinate `(0,0)` with each noose having height `2` and width `1`; the points are named `G-1-0` to `G-1-7`.

The code below uses a `\foreach` loop to draw three black/green pairs of wires, with the wires named `B-0`, `G-0`, `B-1`, `G-1`, `B-2`, and `G-2`. To illustrate the use of the names, some distances are marked with some arbitrary text.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
\newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
\newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
\pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

% \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
\newcommand\wire[5][]%
  {\draw[#1]
    (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
    -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
    -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
    -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
    -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
    {\wire[thick]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
     \wire[thick,green]{G-\i}{{(\i+1)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
    }
  \draw[<-] ($(B-0-2)!0.5!(B-0-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0);
  \draw[<-] ($(G-0-2)!0.5!(G-0-3)$) -- +(0.5,0) node[above]{5mm};
  \draw[<-] ($(G-0-4)!0.5!(G-0-5)$) -- +(-0.5,0);
  \draw[<-] ($(B-1-4)!0.5!(B-1-5)$) -- +(0.5,0) node[above]{7mm};
  \draw[<->] ($(B-1-0)!0.5!(B-1-1)$) -- node[above]{10mm} ($(G-1-0)!0.5!(G-1-1)$);
  \draw[<->] ($(G-1-2)!0.5!(G-1-3)$) -- node[above]{9mm} ($(B-2-2)!0.5!(B-2-3)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Only one thing to say you: May God bless you. May you find your all yeti friends :P

Comment: @L.K. Thanks. May the yeti gods guide you safely through your TeX adventures.