# Hard time in plotting a figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I have to plot the diagram shown in the following picture, but I couldn't find the way to do it in LaTeX.

[image: Description:]

1. There should be three different types of networks (or step lines), green, blue and red.
2. I need to write inside the diagram, as shown in the picture.
3. I have to darken the places where they are very close.

Code provided by @gernot:

```
  \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}

 \newcommand\wireheight{2} % height of one segment
 \newcommand\wirewidth{1}  % width of a segment
 \newcommand\wiredist{0.5} % distance between wires
 \pgfmathsetmacro\pairdist{2*(\wirewidth+\wiredist)} % distance between pairs of wires

 % \wire[options]{name}{start}{height}{width}
 \newcommand\wire[5][]%
   {\draw[#1]
     (#3)            coordinate (#2-0)
     -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-1)
     -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-2)
     -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-3)
     -- ++(-#5,0)    coordinate (#2-4)
     -- ++(0,#4)     coordinate (#2-5)
     -- ++(#5,0)     coordinate (#2-6)
     -- ++(0,0.5*#4) coordinate (#2-7);
   }

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners,>=stealth, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt]
   \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
     {\wire[thick]{B-\i}{\i*\pairdist,0}{\wireheight}{\wirewidth}
      \wire[thick,green]{G-\i}{{(\i+1)*\pairdist-\wiredist},0}{\wireheight}{-\wirewidth}
     }
   \draw[<-] ($(B-0-2)!0.5!(B-0-3)$) -- +(-0.5,0);
   \draw[<-] ($(G-0-2)!0.5!(G-0-3)$) -- +(0.5,0) node[above]{5mm};
   \draw[<-] ($(G-0-4)!0.5!(G-0-5)$) -- +(-0.5,0);
   \draw[<-] ($(B-1-4)!0.5!(B-1-5)$) -- +(0.5,0) node[above]{7mm};
   \draw[<->] ($(B-1-0)!0.5!(B-1-1)$) -- node[above]{10mm} ($(G-1-0)!0.5!(G-1-1)$);
   \draw[<->] ($(G-1-2)!0.5!(G-1-3)$) -- node[above]{9mm} ($(B-2-2)!0.5!(B-2-3)$);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

But this only [gives two arrays](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361665/how-to-plot-this-diagram).

I don't know how to continue from there.

Comment: The precise characteristics of this diagrams are not very clear. Could you explain some details?

Comment: You've tagged this with TikZ. To draw a straight line: `\draw (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2);`. To draw a straight thick line with text above: `\draw [thick] (x1,y1) -- node[above] {text} (x2,y2);`. To draw a dashed red line: `\draw [red,dashed] (x1,y1) -- (x2,y2);`. Commands like this has to be placed between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. You don't really need to know much more to make a diagram like that I think, though there might be ways to to make the code more compact/convenient then a long list of `\draw`s.

Comment: You should put a minimum of effort into your question by showing what you have so far and what the problems are that you are facing, instead of basically saying "please do this for me". Please provide a minimal example whith everything you have managed on your own, including which packages you would use to prepare the drawing.

Comment: @Bernard Let me do that

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf I will put it, eventhough I failed miserably.

Comment: Show us what you've done and we can help you along where you get stuck.

Comment: Why can't you just add more `\draw` commands for the third line or whatever you need? What's the problem in extending it? Don't you just want more of the same, basically?

Comment: @cfr I don't know much about the bendings. Most importantly, the inclined bendings. Is there a way?

Comment: Your sketch just shows straight lines, as far as I can tell. But you can use `bend=left`, say, if you want the lines to bend left.

Comment: If you adjust the position of the coordinates, the lines will be at an angle, right? They are still just straight lines ....