# Add details to TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikZ picture. But couldn't understand how to ad some details.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,yscale=2]
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90, yshift=-128pt] plot(\x,{sin(\x r)});
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90, yshift=-64pt] plot(\x,{cos((\x+1.7) r)});
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90] plot(\x,{sin(\x r)});
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90, yshift=64pt] plot(\x,{cos((\x+1.7) r)});
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90, yshift=128pt] plot(\x,{sin(\x r)});
  \draw[domain=1.5:14.3,samples=300,blue, rotate=90, yshift=192pt] plot(\x,{cos((\x+1.7) r)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to add minimum and maximum distance between the two waves(somewhere around middle of the wave).
Ref: 
[How to plot this diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361665/how-to-plot-this-diagram/361689#361689)

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? A double arrow between the waves?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Somewhere like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361665/how-to-plot-this-diagram/361689#361689), yes double arrow.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have `+1.7` in the cosine functions, and not `+1.57` (approximately pi/2)?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for that input, my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one suggestion, the code is simplified a bit. As you know the minima/maxima of sine/cosine functions, you can just draw two arrows where the y-coordinates are calculated with `sin`/`cos`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   xscale=1,yscale=2,
   every plot/.append style={samples=50,domain=1.5:14.3},
   rotate=90]

\begin{scope}[blue]
  \draw plot(\x,{sin(\x r) - 5});
  \draw plot(\x,{cos((\x+pi/2) r) - 2.5});
  \draw plot(\x,{sin(\x r)});
  \draw plot(\x,{cos((\x+pi/2) r) + 2.5});
  \draw plot(\x,{sin(\x r) + 5});
  \draw plot(\x,{cos((\x+pi/2) r) + 7.5});
\end{scope}

  \draw [<->,>=stealth] (5*pi/2,{sin(5*pi/2 r)}) -- node[above] {$a$} (5*pi/2,{cos((5*pi/2+pi/2) r)+2.5});
  \draw [<->,>=stealth] (5*pi/2,{sin(5*pi/2 r)}) -- node[above] {$b$} (5*pi/2,{cos((5*pi/2+pi/2) r)-2.5});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```